# Encontrar un objeto por el nombre en mysql y node js

Tags: javascript, mysql, nodejs

¿Cómo puedo buscar en vez de por el ID, por un parámetro como NAME y que me devuelva sus valores para mostrarlos al usar un buscador?

```
router.get('/:id', (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body)
    const { id } = req.params;
    connection.query(`SELECT * FROM product WHERE category = ?`, [id], (err, rows, fields) => {
        if (!err) {
            res.json(rows)
        } else {
            console.log(err);
        }

    })
})
```

Comment: Pues cambia la consulta para buscar por el parámetro que necesitas.

Comment: Manda un undefined parece q hay q aplicar un método en específico pero no sé cómo emplearlo se llama LIKE

Comment: Usa algo como `SELECT * FROM product WHERE category LIKE ?` y al pasar el parámetro como segundo argumento `['%' + category + '%']` donde `category` es la variable que tiene la cadena que quieres matchear con algo.

Comment: Muchas gracias voy a probarlo 

Comment: Recomendaria explorar https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/getting-started/ es un ORM que permite realizar consultas a bases de datos relacionales como Postgres, MySQL, y otras de manera mas sencilla.

Comment: Grácias pero debo hacerlo con mysql puro u.u

Comment: Lo probé pero no me da u.u nc si es q estoy aplicándolo mal